# How to custom loss function in a lightgbm regression model

Tags: python, lightgbm

I tried to custom a loss function for lightgbm model, however, i always met the TpyeError "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'", please find the code below.

```
def my_loss_func(y_pred, data):
    error = data.get_label() - y_pred
    w = data.get_weight()
    loss = (w * error ** 2).mean()

    return 'custom_loss', loss, False


def objective(params, X, y, weight):
    train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y, train_weight, val_weight = train_test_split(X, y, weight, random_state=42)

    train_glgbm = lgb.Dataset(train_X, label=train_y)
    train_glgbm.set_weight(train_weight)
    val_glgbm = lgb.Dataset(val_X, label=val_y, reference=train_glgbm)
    val_glgbm.set_weight(val_weight)

    model = lgb.train(params, train_glgbm, num_boost_round=1000, valid_sets=[val_glgbm],
                      early_stopping_rounds=100,
                      feval=my_loss_func,
                      verbose_eval=False)

    y_pred = model.predict(val_X, num_iteration=model.best_iteration)
    score = my_loss_func(y_pred, val_glgbm)

    # release memory
    del train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y, train_glgbm, val_glgbm, model, y_pred
    gc.collect()

    return {'loss': score[1], 'status': STATUS_OK, 'params': params}

space = {
    "max_depth": hp.choice('max_depth', range(2, 15, 1)),
    "num_trees": hp.choice('num_trees', range(10, 301, 1)),
    'learning_rate': hp.uniform('learning_rate', 1e-3, 5e-1),
    "bagging_fraction": hp.uniform("bagging_fraction", 0, 1),
    "num_leaves": hp.choice('num_leaves', range(5, 50, 1)),
    "min_data_per_leaf": hp.choice('min_data_per_leaf', range(5, 50, 1)),
    "objective":hp.choice('objective', ['regression']),
    "metric":None,
    "custom_metric": hp.choice('custom_metric', ['my_loss_func'])
}

weight = np.ones_like(y)
best = fmin(fn=lambda params: objective(params, X, y, weight), 
            space=space, 
            algo=tpe.suggest, 
            max_evals=20, 
            verbose= 1)
```

when I add "print(w)" to the my_loss_func function, it prints None, I am confuse about this issue, thanks a lot for any advice.

how to address the TypeError problem in my code.